# Blank fields in repeating table makes form un-editable

Tags: 2010, infopath-rules

We have an info path 2010 webform on SharePoint 2010 with a few repeating tables using cascading drop down fields to gather info.  The problem is when a user does not complete all the fields in the repeating table and adds an item then saves to come back later, they are unable to edit the drop downs when they reopen the form.  We are able to open the form in info path from SharePoint, delete the added empty rows to fix it, but would like to not have to do this each time someone has an issue.  Ideally we would like to prevent a row from being added until all the fields in the current row are complete.